# increment letter variables in awk

Tags: split, awk, increment, prefix

In a script like this for splitting a large file by string:

```
awk  '/MYSTRING/ {n++}{print >"out_" n ".txt" }' LARGEFILE
```

This produces out_1.txt, out_2.txt, etc.

How can I get letter prefixes as produced by split (out_aa.txt, out_ab.txt, out_ac.txt, ...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not very straight forward so allow me to use some modulo arithmetic here like this:

```
awk '/MYSTRING/ {n++} {p=97+int(n/26); q=(n%26)+97; s=sprintf("out_%c%c.txt", p, q); print > s}' LARGEFILE
```

Comment: This is a keeper @anubhava!! +1

Comment: +1, i thought that using brace expansion would be easier, but I was wrong.

Comment: Good! BTW I think you have an extra `'`.

Comment: Thanks @potong: corrected it. I like your answer too for the alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk  -vv "$(echo {a..z}{a..z})" 'BEGIN{split(v,a);n++} /MYSTRING/ {n++}{print >"out_" a[n] ".txt" }' LARGEFILE
```